# Automatically call a method when any method of a class is called in PHP

Tags: php

I have a ORM-type class that I use to update rows in the database.  When I pass an object of this class to my DAO, I want the DAO to only update the fields in the object that changed (the SQL query should only contain the changed columns).  Right now I'm just keeping track of every time a setter method is called and using this to determine which fields changed.

But this means I have to duplicate the same code in every setter method.  Is there a way in PHP that I can create a method which is automatically called any time any method in the class is called?  The `__call` magic method only works for non-existent methods. I want something like that, but for existing methods.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
class Car{
  private $id;
  private $make;
  private $model;

  private $modifiedFields = array();

  public function getMake(){ return $this->make; }

  public function setMake($make){
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->modified(__METHOD__);
  }

  //getters and setters for other fields

  private function modified($method){
    if (preg_match("/.*?::set(.*)/", $method, $matches)){
      $field = $matches[1];
      $field[0] = strtolower($field[0]);
      $this->modifiedFields[] = $field;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I want:

```
class Car{
  private $id;
  private $make;
  private $model;

  private $modifiedFields = array();

  public function getMake(){ return $this->make; }

  public function setMake($make){
    //the "calledBeforeEveryMethodCall" method is called before entering this method
    $this->make = $make;
  }

  //getters and setters for other fields

  private function calledBeforeEveryMethodCall($method){
    if (preg_match("/.*?::set(.*)/", $method, $matches)){
      $field = $matches[1];
      $field[0] = strtolower($field[0]);
      $this->modifiedFields[] = $field;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are open to other ORM's Doctrine 2 handles this transparently without poisoning your domain with ORM specific code. Basically it takes the more robust approach of calculating changes just before they are committed instead of trying to keep track of them constantly; which means keeping a copy of the original object when it is first retrieved. Doctrine 2 documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/

Comment: @rojoca No, I don't want to use an ORM framework.  I just need this to work for this class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could name all your setters in a generic way, like:

`protected function _setABC`

and define `__call` as something like:

```
<?php
public function __call($name, $args) {
   if (method_exists($this, '_', $name)) {
      return call_user_func_array(array($this, '_', $name), $args);
   }
}
```

Comment: I want my setters to remain public though.  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael Yoshi's example works even if the function is public instead of protected. He meant to imply that you should change setMake() to _setMake(). the __call() function is executed when a function of the class is called but isn't known. So you can still use $obj->setMake(), which would use __call('setMake', array(args)).